# WCF Proxy setup

Tags: wcf, proxy

I have a WCF service setup and its been running well. However, I need to know how to setup a WCF proxy client step-by-step. I have done a lot of research on the net but can't find a good example. Also once you have specified the proxy address how do you setup a proxy address to allow WCF service to communicate?

So far I have done this...

```
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("PROXYNAME",PORTNUMBER);
webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DOMAIN);
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;
```

After I have done this code and call it what i'm I missing?

Comment: Check [this turorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the "Learning WCF" book (a little outdated, but does what you seem to be asking). Here are the book samples you can use to take a look: http://www.thatindigogirl.com/LearningWCFCode.aspx

From what it sounds like, you have the service portion complete but now need to create a client that creates an instance of your service. These samples should show you how to do this pretty quickly.